# Evaluating the Fourier coefficients of $abs(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, absolute-value

Let's get started:

$$\hat f(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |x|e^{-inx} dx$$

since $|x|$ is an even function:

$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} xe^{-inx} dx$$

Integration by parts yields:

$$e^{-inx}\Big|_0^{\pi} + \frac{1}{in} \int_0^\pi e^{-inx} dx = (-1)^n - 1 + \frac{1}{in} \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{-in} + \frac{1}{in} \right) \\ = (-1)^n - 1 + \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{n^2}$$

So if $n$ is even then $\hat f(n) = 0$. Otherwise:

$$\hat f(n) = \frac{1}{\pi} \left( -2 -\frac{2}{n^2} \right)$$

but that doesn't make sense since we know that $\hat f(n) \to 0$.

Where is my mistake?

**EDIT**
it should be

$$x e^{-inx}\Big|_0^{\pi} + \frac{1}{in} \int_0^\pi e^{-inx} dx = \frac{\pi e^{-in\pi}}{-in} + \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{n^2}$$

So $$\hat f(n) = \frac{1}{\pi} \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{-in} + \frac{(-1)^n - 1}{n^2} \right)$$

Comment: Your first term in the integration by parts is not correct.

Comment: I also have issues with your equality after "is an even function." The absolute value function is not  periodic, so it seems to me you have to decide which part of the domain you are going to use - given your definition of the FT, as integral over $[0,2\pi]$, you have as definition
$$\hat f (n) = {1\over 2 \pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 x e^{-i n x}\,dx.$$
On the other hand, given your "even" comment, if we take as "fundamental domain" $[-\pi,\pi]$, then
$$ \hat f(n)=   {1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |x| e^{-i n x}\,dx = {1\over 2\pi}\int^\pi_0 x ( e^{- inx } + e^{inx}) \,dx.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|x|$ is positive in $[0, 2 \pi]$, then
\begin{align}
\hat f(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \int_0^{2\pi} |x|e^{-inx} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \int_{0}^{2\pi} x \, e^{-i n x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \left[ \int_{0}^{\pi} x \, e^{-i n x} \, dx + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} x \, e^{-i n x} \, dx \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \left[ \int_{0}^{\pi} x \, e^{-i n x} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} (x+\pi) \, e^{-i n (x+\pi)} \, dx \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} \left[ x + (-1)^{n} (x+\pi) \right]  \, e^{-i n x} \, dx \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \, \left\{ \left[\frac{i}{n} \left(x + (-1)^{n} (x+\pi)\right) + \frac{1+ (-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}\right] \, e^{-i n x} \right\}_{0}^{\pi} \\
&= \frac{i \, (1 + (-1)^{n})}{2 \, n}  
\end{align}
This leads to
\begin{align}
\hat f(2n) &= \frac{i}{2n} \\
\hat f(2n+1) &= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: mistake : the $1/n^2$ term disappeared

Comment: Why are you evaluating the integral from 0 until 2pi and not from negative pi to pi?

Answer (score 3):

The first mistake is in :

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |x|e^{-inx} dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} xe^{-inx} dx\:\:\:$  since $|x|$ is an even function .

This is false because $\:e^{-inx}\:$ is not an even function.

The supposed equality is true if $\:n\:$ is even. It is false if $\:n\:$ is odd.